# Generating Shapes from a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, graphics

Good Evening All,

The idea is to create a series of colour blocks that sit on top of each other in a vertical column (See picture) by iterating through a dictionary. I can’t seem to get it right.

This is what I've attempted so far.

This is what I am [aiming for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgZQR.png).
This is what I am able to [create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP40m.png).

Any hints welcomed!

```
import tkinter

from collections import OrderedDict


def main():

    dict1 = OrderedDict()

    dict1['Block1'] = [70, 'red', '1st column']
    dict1['Block2'] = [200, 'green', '1st column']
    dict1['Block3'] = [420, 'blue', '1st column']


    canvas = make_canvas(200, 800, dict1['Block1'][2])


    for key in dict1.keys():
        canvas.create_rectangle(20, 40, 100, dict1[key][0], fill=dict1[key][1])  # Create a block for each key

    canvas.mainloop()



def make_canvas(width, height, title=None):
    objects = {}
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.minsize(width=width, height=height)
    if title:
        top.title(title)
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(top, width=width + 1, height=height + 1)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.xview_scroll(8, 'units')  # add this so (0, 0) works correctly
    canvas.yview_scroll(8, 'units')  # otherwise it's clipped off

    return canvas


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that canvas is drawing different bars starting from the *same* position which overwrites the previous one.

You need start at the previous total and end at the total plus the length of the bar.

```
import tkinter

from collections import OrderedDict


def main():

    dict1 = OrderedDict()

    dict1['Block1'] = [70, 'red', '1st column']
    dict1['Block2'] = [200, 'green', '1st column']
    dict1['Block3'] = [420, 'blue', '1st column']


    canvas = make_canvas(200, 800, dict1['Block1'][2])

    total = 0
    for key in dict1.keys():
        canvas.create_rectangle(20, total, 100, total + dict1[key][0], fill=dict1[key][1])  # Create a block for each key
        total += dict1[key][0]

    canvas.mainloop()



def make_canvas(width, height, title=None):
    objects = {}
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.minsize(width=width, height=height)
    if title:
        top.title(title)
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(top, width=width + 1, height=height + 1)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.xview_scroll(8, 'units')  # add this so (0, 0) works correctly
    canvas.yview_scroll(8, 'units')  # otherwise it's clipped off

    return canvas


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi WyattBlue. Thanks for your solution. It is clear and concise! I gave you an upvote but the system said it won't publicly register it because my reputation is less than 15.